# How do I get rid of the space at the end of a word in paste0 function?

Tags: r, string

I have the following code:

```
canada <- c(50, 50, 50)
korea <- c(70, 70, 70)
brazil <- c(100, 100, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")
```

I want it to look like this:

```
There are 50 thousand farms in Canada.
```

This is what I tried:

```
one <- function(x){
  x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[x,]
  country <- paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x))

  count <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                  function(x, n, i){paste0(x)},
                  x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
  count[length(count)] <- paste0(count[length(count)])
  count <- paste0(count[1])

  cat("There are", count, "thousand farms in", country, ".")
}
cat(one("canada"))
```

But, this is what I get:

```
There are 50 thousand farms in Canada .
```

I need to keep the code I've demonstrated here. So far, I tried the **paste** function, but I know that **paste0** should be what I am using for getting rid of the space at the end. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using paste0? Just replace cat with paste0. You may need to add whitespace at beginning and end of each string literals.

Comment: I don't understand your use of `paste0`. Why are you pasting just one vector element, as in `paste0(count[1])` and other places?

Comment: I am using this as an example to represent a bulkier script, and using paste0 in lieu of cat does not work for the bulkier script : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `paste0` on string parts instead of counts. and write spaces you need manually.
like this:

```
one <- function(x){
  x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[x,]
  country <- paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x))

  count <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                  function(x, n, i){paste0(x)},
                  x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
  count[length(count)] <- paste0(count[length(count)])
  count <- count[1]

  cat(paste0("There are ", count, " thousand farms in ", country, "."))
}
one("canada")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an r programmer so I don't know the syntax that well. But in Python this could be fixed as followed

```
one <- function(x){
      x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
      myrow <- fruit[x,]
      country <- paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x))

      count <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                      function(x, n, i){paste0(x)},
                      x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
      count[length(count)] <- paste0(count[length(count)])
      count <- paste0(count[1])

      cat("There are "+ str(count) " thousand farms in "+ country + ".")
    }
    cat(one("canada"))
```

What I am trying to do here is instead of `,` I use concatenation that is `+` and `str(count)` to change integer value of `count` to a string value.

Comment: This code looks the same as the one by SirSaleh posted two minutes prior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm completely off, but the following does the same and is much simpler.

```
one <- function(x){
  x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  count <- fruit[x, 1]
  country <- paste0(tools::toTitleCase(x))

  cat(paste0("There are ", count, " thousand farms in ", country, ".\n"))
}

one("canada")
There are 50 thousand farms in Canada.

one("korea")
There are 70 thousand farms in Korea.

one("brazil")
There are 100 thousand farms in Brazil.
```

If I didn't understand it, please excuse the noise.

Comment: Thanks! However, I actually needs the lesser simple version because the code is used in the bulkier version : )

Comment: @JimO. Ok, I believe that I should mention that without a final newline at the end of the `cat` instruction, it will remain in the same line. Add it after the end period, like this, `".\n"`.